# jquery count hover event

Tags: jquery, events, hover

I want to count how much time ,I am mouseovering  on an html  element.

for eample

link

```
<a class="mylink">Check me Out !</a>
```

jquery

```
jQuery('.mylink').hover(function(){

//what should i do here to count
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, ;) jquery is more like ... French! :p

Comment: On second read, can you clarify if you want to count how many times you're hovering over an element, or get the length of time you're hovering over the element for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep a separate counter for each matched element do the following:

```
jquery('.mylink').mouseover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var count = parseInt($this.data('count'), 10) + 1;
    $this.data('count', count);
});
```

Then you can get the count for each element using `$(selector).data('count')`.

Edit: Fixed stupid mistake.

Comment: +1 nice and clean solution. Maybe I'm stupid, but haven't you forgotten adding `1` to the count every time?

Comment: Lol, 2 upvotes and 4 hours later, someone noticed it. Thanks.:)

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function()
{
    var myCounter = 0;
    $('.mylink').mouseover(function()
    {
        myCounter++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how many seconds you have been hovering over an element try this:

```
$('.mylink').hover(
    //mouseover handler
    function(){
        //record the current time
        $(this).data( 'start', new Date().getTime() );
    },
    //mouseout handler
    function(){
        //grab the end time
        var end = new Date().getTime();
        //calculate the difference in seconds
        var hoverTime = ( end - $(this).data('start') )/1000;
        //use the result
        alert( hoverTime.toFixed( 2 ) );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

call this function ...

```
jquery('.mylink').hover(function(){

start(true)
});


function start(isStarted, index){
if(!index){
 index = 0;
 }

 if(isStarted) {
 started[index] = true;
 counter[index] =0;

 }


if(started[index] && true) {
 counter[index] += 1;
 timer = setTimeout("start(false," + index + ")",1000);
 }

}
```