# How to check how long you hover an element

Tags: jquery

Is it possible using jQuery to 'time' how long the cursor is hovering over a certain element? It would be nice if someone could put me in the right direction.

Thijs

Comment: repeated and answered there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974617/jquery-count-hover-event

Comment: I'm sorry didn't saw that post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it using jQuery's [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) - you can basically store the start time in the element's `.data`, and compare it to `Date().getTime()` when the mouse leaves.

Knocked up a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XQ9kY/1/

The HTML:

```
<div id="hoverZone" class="hoverable">
    You can hover over me<br />for as long as you like
</div>
<div id="hoverResult">
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('.hoverable').hover(   
    function(){       
        $(this).data('inTime', new Date().getTime());
    },    
    function(){       
        var outTime = new Date().getTime();       
        var hoverTime = (outTime - $(this).data('inTime'))/1000;        
        $('#hoverResult').html('you were hovering for ' + hoverTime + 's');
    }
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to count seconds without mouse leave? because i need to load the data after three second not pre-loaded data.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the hover function to do that.  Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myElement').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).data("hoverStart", (new Date()).getTime());
        }, 
        function() {
            var hoverTime = ((new Date()).getTime() - $(this).data("hoverStart")) / 1000;

            alert("You hovered for " + hoverTime +  " seconds.");
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used 'Hover Intent' to delay JQuery functions before: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html - if that's what you mean.