# Counting hover times with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am new to JavaScript. I want to count how many times the mouse hovers over a certain word. I tried the code shown here - [jquery count hover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974617/jquery-count-hover-event) - but obviously I'm not doing something right.

For example:

```
<div>
<p>The quick <a class="link1" style="color:#ff0000;">brown</a> fox
   jumps over the <a class="link2" style="color:#ff0000;">lazy</a> 
   <a class="link3" style="color:#ff0000;">dog</a>.</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jquery('.link1').mouseover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var count = parseInt($this.data('count'), 10) + 1;
    $this.data('count', count);
});
```

and I repeat this with `link2` and `link3` for "lazy" and "dog", but it doesn't work. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is, your anchor element doesnt have any `data-count`, which will cause error at the time of hover. Add that attribute it will work fine.

```
<div>
    <p>The quick <a class="link1" data-count="0" style="color:#ff0000;">brown</a> fox jumps over the <a class="link2" data-count="0" style="color:#ff0000;">lazy</a> 
        <a class="link3" data-count="0" style="color:#ff0000;">dog</a>.</p>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.link1').mouseover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var count = parseInt($this.data('count'), 10) + 1;
    $this.data('count', count);
    alert($this.data('count'));
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/191/)

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are using `jquery` and not `jQuery` or `$`.

Note that `Q` is captial

Answer (score 2):

Issues that you need to fix:

- Make sure you use either `jQuery` or `$`
- Make sure you hook up your even in the jQuery load function (or somewhere it will actually get called)
- Make sure you initialize data-count *or* you check for undefined when you get this the first time.
- You can combine all selectors with a comma

I fixed these and have pasted the result below:

**JSFiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/85MSt/1/

**HTML**

```
<p>The quick <a class="link1" data-count="0">brown</a> fox jumps over the <a class="link2" data-count="0">lazy</a>
    <a class="link3" data-count="0">dog</a>.
</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $('.link1, .link2, .link3').mouseover(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var count = parseInt($this.data('count'), 10) + 1;
      $this.data('count', count);
    });
});
```

Best of luck!